# undirected graph what is the possible minimum spanning tree?

Tags: graph-algorithm, minimum, greedy, kruskals-algorithm

I try to solve this question but I am not sure of my solution

[the quetion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbl9f.png)

This is my solution:
I use Kruskal algorithm
and I choose the edges that will make (a) leaf
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Id4.jpg)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. The answer will be 9. The algorithm takes edges:
a<->b with cost 1: ADDED a,b are now connected
a<->d with cost 1: ADDED a,b,d are now connected
b<->d with cost 4: SKIPPED
c<->d with cost 7: ADDED a,b,d,c are now connected, this is the final spanning tree.
a<->c with cost 8: SKIPPED
b<->c with cost 12: SKIPPED

So, the answer is 1+1+7=9.

Comment: but like this the node (a) will not be a leaf of the tree ??

Comment: Ah, I see. Then your answer is correct. But you cannot use Kruskal algorithm, because it does not guarantee any node to be a leaf in the final spanning tree. Kruskal algorithm would give you the answer i gave, that is 9. In such small graph you can easily find all possible spanning trees and compare them. But if you want non-brute force algorithm to find minimal spanning tree with this additional requirement you will need different algorithm than Kruskal, and I don't know at the moment what algorithm would you need.

Comment: thank you , i found an example of this questuin and like you said no need for Kruskal.